# ServiceStack BasicAuthentication and IIS7.5

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, basic-authentication

I'm using basic authentication with my service stack API.  I use the following code.

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider() }));
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

var userRepository = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRepository);
// User details added here
```

In my client I use the following:

```
 _client = new JsonServiceClient(_settings.ServiceUrl);
 _client.SetCredentials(settings.ApiUser, settings.ApiPassword);
```

When my service stack service is running locally from visual studios it works fine.  However if I host it on IIS7.5 I get "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

The user name and password is correct.
Is there anything I might be missing in the IIS setup that might be causing this?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your implementation.  I have an api that's using basic auth on IIS 7.5 without any special configuration.  What happens if you pull up the REST url in a browser and login manually?  Can you get in that way?

Comment: @JeffMitchell: Thanks for your reply. When I login locally it works.  With the same code hosted on IIS the login fails and I'm prompted with the login dialog again. I'm completely baffled by this one!

Comment: I think you can rule out any problems with the JsonServiceClient then.  Perhaps something with your authentication process on your production server.  Different user database, having trouble connecting to the data store, etc.  Perhaps start looking in that direction.  Add some logging if you can.